# applying ddply over multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I have a ddply function that performs a calculation after grouping by a specific column (DateTimeminuteFloor).  This function works, but only over a single dataframe.  I'm trying to apply it over a list of dataframes, but am receiving an error.

Working function:

```
data1<- ddply(data1, .(DateTimeminuteFloor), transform, 
  val_1 = MidBidAsk[1],
  change = (MidBidAsk - MidBidAsk[1]))
```

I now have a list of dataframes (could be hundreds):

```
framelist= c("data1","data2","data3")
```

I've tried the following, but am receiving the below error:

```
for (i in framelist) {
i <- ddply(i, .(DateTimeminuteFloor), transform, 
  val_1 = MidBidAsk[1],
  change = (MidBidAsk - MidBidAsk[1]))
}
```

Error in if (empty(.data)) return(.data) :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

The dataframes in the list are not empty.
Thanks

Comment: But `framelist` is _not_ a list of data frames. It is a character vector (presumably with the _names_ of data frames), so you are passing the _string_ `"data1"` in the first iteration to `ddply`  instead of a data frame. Where are your data frames? Are they all in your global environment? Are they in a list? If they are in the global environment (and it sounds like a really bad idea to have hundreds of data frames in the global environment), you could try using `get(i)` instead of `i` as the first argument to `ddply`

Comment: Hi Allan

I'm new to R.  I've tried substituting get(i) instead of i, which removes the error, but doesn't actually alter the dataframe.   If you could advise me on how to create an actual list of these dataframes (instead of a character vector with their names), I'd appreciate it.  Thanks